# Detecting whether .exe was closed

Tags: c#, winforms, exe

I need to insert part of code after user closes .exe which I run like this(it is foxpro exe):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
string openexe= @"C:\Users\marek\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\tours\tours\bin\Debug\netpokl.exe";
Process.Start(openexe);
}
```

I thought that it could work something like this:

```
string otevriExe = @"C:\Users\marek\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\tours\tours\bin\Debug\netpokl.exe";
string b = Process.Start(otevriExe);
                 b.Closed += b_Closed;
void b_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // mycode    
}
```

Would someone please help me to improve my code so it would work? Thank you everyone for time and answers.

Comment: Have you tried `p.Exited += (sender, e) => { /*your code here*/ };` ?

Comment: Hello sorry, but I don't know exactly how to implement this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
string openexe= @"C:\Users\marek\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\tours\tours\bin\Debug\netpokl.exe";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = openexe;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
//do stuff here
```

EDIT: seeing as you're starting it on a button click, rather use an event handler:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        string openexe= @"C:\Users\marek\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\tours\tours\bin\Debug\netpokl.exe";
        p.StartInfo.FileName = openexe;
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.Exited +=new EventHandler(p_Exited);
        p.Start();            
    }

 private void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do stuff here
        MessageBox.Show("Exited");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event (note: you need to set `EnableRaisingEvents` to true) e.g. :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string openexe= @"C:\Users\marek\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\tours\tours\bin\Debug\netpokl.exe";
    var proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(openexe);
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    proc.Exited += new EventHandler(proc_Exited);
    proc.Start();
}

private void proc_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // the process has exited...
}
```

This is the asynchronous way, for a synchronous approach you can use the [`WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx) method :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string openexe= @"C:\Users\marek\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\tours\tours\bin\Debug\netpokl.exe";
    var proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(openexe);
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    // here the process has exited...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
b.Exited += b_Closed;

void b_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // mycode    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `EnableRaisingEvents` to `True` and listen to the `Exited` event.

```
string otevriExe = @"C:\Users\marek\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\tours\tours\bin\Debug\netpokl.exe";
Process b = Process.Start(otevriExe);
b.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
b.Exited += (s, e) => 
{

};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do your stuff [onExited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.onexited.aspx) event. Like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyProcess p = new MyProcess();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    p.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_HasExited);
    p.Start();       
}
private static void myProcess_HasExited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Process has exited.");
}
```